# How to return Struct from Hive UDF?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I am having trouble finding documentation on how to use a Hive UDF to return a Struct.

My major questions are:

What types of objects do I start with in Java?

How do I convert them so they will be interpreted as a Struct in Hive?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a very simple example of such kind of UDF.
It receives an User-Agent string, parse it using external lib and returns a structure with 4 text fields:

STRUCT<type: string, os: string, family: string, device: string>

You need to extend **GenericUDF** class and override two most important methods: **initialize** and **evaluate**.

**initialize()** describes the structure itself and defines data types inside.

**evaluate()** fills up the structure with actual values.

You don't need any special classes to return, struct<> in Hive is just an array of objects in Java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import eu.bitwalker.useragentutils.UserAgent;

public class UAStructUDF extends GenericUDF {

    private Object[] result;

    @Override
    public String getDisplayString(String[] arg0) {
        return "My display string";
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arg0) throws UDFArgumentException {
        // Define the field names for the struct<> and their types
        ArrayList<String> structFieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<ObjectInspector> structFieldObjectInspectors = new ArrayList<ObjectInspector>();

        // fill struct field names
        // type
        structFieldNames.add("type");
        structFieldObjectInspectors.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
        //family
        structFieldNames.add("family");
        structFieldObjectInspectors.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
        // OS name
        structFieldNames.add("os");
        structFieldObjectInspectors.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
        // device
        structFieldNames.add("device");
        structFieldObjectInspectors.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);

        StructObjectInspector si = ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(structFieldNames,
                structFieldObjectInspectors);
        return si;
    }

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] args) throws HiveException {
        if (args == null || args.length < 1) {
            throw new HiveException("args is empty");
        }
        if (args[0].get() == null) {
            throw new HiveException("args contains null instead of object");
        }

        Object argObj = args[0].get();

        // get argument
        String argument = null;     
        if (argObj instanceof Text){
            argument = ((Text) argObj).toString();
        } else if (argObj instanceof String){
            argument = (String) argObj;
        } else {
            throw new HiveException("Argument is neither a Text nor String, it is a " + argObj.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        }
        // parse UA string and return struct, which is just an array of objects: Object[] 
        return parseUAString(argument);
    }

    private Object parseUAString(String argument) {
        result = new Object[4];
        UserAgent ua = new UserAgent(argument);
        result[0] = new Text(ua.getBrowser().getBrowserType().getName());
        result[1] = new Text(ua.getBrowser().getGroup().getName());
        result[2] = new Text(ua.getOperatingSystem().getName());
        result[3] = new Text(ua.getOperatingSystem().getDeviceType().getName());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of SerDe ( serializer and deserialzer ) in HIVE that can be used with the kind of data format you are playing it. It serializes the objects (complex) and then de-serializes it according to the need.
For instance, if you have a JSON file, that contains objects and values, so you need a way to store that content in hive.
For that you weill use a JsonSerde, that is actually a jar file , containing the parser code written in java for playing around with Json data.

SO now you have a jar( SerDe), and the other requirement is for a schema to store that data.
For eg: for XML files you need XSD,
similarly for JSON you define object ,arrays and structures relations.
You can check this link:
http://thornydev.blogspot.in/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html
Please let me know if this helps and solves your purpose :)